# How do you view the methods for a class in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-3.0, android-studio-2.2, android-studio-2.3

I am moving from Eclipse to Android Studio, and my faint recollection is that there was a way to list all the methods of a class in Eclipse.  Then, you could click on them and jump to the code.

Is there a way to do this in Android Studio?

Thank you.

Comment: If you are a Windows / Linux user. Press the Ctrl button and point mouse cursor on specific method to move.

Answer (score 1):

You can enable that panel on `View -> Tool Windows -> Structure`